# Glassfish crash on redeploy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish

I start glassfish with `start-domain domain1 --debug=true` from the asadmin script inside  glassfish(toplevel glassfish folder)/bin folder. I then use the redeploy goal and it works about 1-2 times then the following error appears is it possible to fix this? It is like the server is shutting down. I also use JRebel.

```
[INFO] --- maven-glassfish-plugin:2.1:redeploy (default-cli) @ MyApp ---
Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/release/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/external/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 5.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://maven.ocean.net.au/snapshot/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to release.ocean.net.au (http://maven.ocean.net.au/release): maven.ocean.net.au
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to external.ocean.net.au (http://maven.ocean.net.au/external): maven.ocean.net.au
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api/maven-metadata.xml from/to snapshot.ocean.net.au (http://maven.ocean.net.au/snapshot): maven.ocean.net.au
[INFO] No such local command, undeploy. To run remote commands, start the application server (e.g. 'asadmin start-domain').
[ERROR] 'JAVA_OPTS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[ERROR] operable program or batch file.
[ERROR] Remote server does not listen for requests on [localhost:4848]. Is the server up?
[ERROR] Undeployment of MyApp failed.
[ERROR] For more detail on what might be causing the problem try running maven with the --debug option 
[ERROR] or setting the maven-glassfish-plugin "echo" property to "true".
```

Having this config in POM:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <glassfish.home>${env.GLASSFISH_HOME}</glassfish.home>
        <glassfish.directory>${glassfish.home}/glassfish</glassfish.directory>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                    <domain>
                        <name>domain1</name>
                        <adminPort>4848</adminPort>
                        <httpPort>8080</httpPort>
                        <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                    </domain>
                    <glassfishDirectory>${glassfish.home}</glassfishDirectory>
                    <passwordFile>${glassfish.directory}/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords</passwordFile>
                    <user>admin</user>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: I tried to change JDK to 32 bit, did not help. Using JDK 7 on Windows 7, 64 bit. It is caused by a JVM error.